# How to Insert new item into session without overriding the previous value ASP / VB.NET

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, session

I am making a website using ASP and VB.net (I have a mysql database with all the products stored in it), I need to create an add to cart button to display it in the cart later on.

For this, I decided to store the item ID from the database into a session variable and retrieve it back on the cart page to display the other information about the product. but I need to add a new variable to the session array every time the user clicks the button to add an item to the cart. but I cannot figure out how to add a variable to the array everytime its clicked.

```
    Private _cmd As MySqlCommand
    Private _adapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("Cart")
    Dim item As Integer
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ViewProduct()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ViewProduct()
        Dim Cart(10) As String
        Dim QueryStr As String
        _conn = New MySqlConnection
        _conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ProductConn").ConnectionString
        Dim _reader As MySqlDataReader
        _conn.Open()

        QueryStr = "SELECT * FROM products.items "
        _cmd = New MySqlCommand(QueryStr, _conn)
        _reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader()

        For index As Integer = 0 To 48 Step 1
            _reader.Read()
            If Request.RawUrl = "/ZTY_Fashion/Scripts/Viewproduct.aspx?id=" + _reader("productID").ToString Then
                ImageButton1.ImageUrl = _reader("productImg").ToString
                name.Text = _reader("productName").ToString
                product.Text = _reader("productDisc").ToString
                price.Text = _reader("productPrice").ToString
                addtocart.Text = "Buy Now"
                quantity.Text = "Quantity in stock" + " " + _reader("Instock").ToString
                quantitytxt.Text = "Quantity"
                similar.Text = "Similar Items in stock"
                ID.Text = _reader("productID").ToString

            End If
        Next index

        _reader.Close()

        Dim rnd = New Random()
        Dim nextValue = rnd.Next(48) / 1

        QueryStr = "SELECT * FROM products.items WHERE productID='" & nextValue & "'"
        _cmd = New MySqlCommand(QueryStr, _conn)
        _reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader()

        For i As Integer = 0 To 48 Step 1
            _reader.Read()
            Select Case i
                Case 0
                    imgdisplay.ImageUrl = _reader("productImg").ToString
            End Select
        Next i

        _reader.Close()
        _conn.Close()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub addtocart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button20.Click

    //This is where i would like to add the code
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your own custom list of objects in a session, Then just make a collection of these objects to store in your session, such as a `List<CustomerCartItem>`. Convert it to VB.net as it is in c#

Create a Class

```
public class CustomerCartItem
{
   // add what you need here, if you dont need quantity or name, just remove 
   // both, and only take Product ID
   public int ProductID {get;set;}
   public int Quantity {get;set;}
   public int Name {get;set;}
}
```

When You are going to add new Product in Cart

```
if(Session["customerCartItem"] != null){
   List<CustomerCartItem> items = (List<CustomerCartItem>)Session["customerCartItem"];
   items.Add(new CustomerCartItem() { ProductID = 1, Quantity = 2, Name = 'Prod1' }) 
   Session["customerCartItem"] =   items ;
}
else
{
List<CustomerCartItem> items = new List<CustomerCartItem>();
items.Add(new CustomerCartItem() { ProductID = 1, Quantity = 2, Name = 'Prod2' })
Session["customerCartItem"] =   items ;
}
```